# Node.js backend with external jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt, nestjs

We have this scenario, it has an application to manage users and app's permissions, and also it has a JWT service to generate JWT.
The frontends call to JWT service (through own login form) in order to get JWT and send it in the http header to an specific backend.

[image]

All this frontends and backends are build in the same technologies.
We want to start to implement Node.js, so we are developing our first backend with node.js. But I would like to still use the JWT service and the application to manage users and app's permissions.

The new frontend is build in Angular, it calls to JWT Service and it makes petitions to the backend with the JWT, until here everything works.

But I have to create a user's table in my new database in order to create some database's constraint and logs. So the backend has a UserRepository and it implements jwt-strategy in this way:

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { UserService } from 'src/core/user/user.service';
import { CreateUserDto } from 'src/core/user/dtos';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    });
  }
  async validate(payload: any) {

    // 1. Search the user is backend's table's database
    let user =  await this.userService.getOneByName(payload.username);
    
    if(user == null || user == undefined) {
      // 2. if the user is not register in the backend's table's database, It must be registered
      const newUser: CreateUserDto = {name: payload.username, lastName: '', email: '', roles: payload.role};

      user = await this.userService.createOne(newUser);
      
      // 3. it returns the registered user
      return user;
    }
    
    // it returns the user from backend database
    return user;
  }
}
```

how about security?

is this code a good way to implement a external jwt in node.js?

Comment: what is 'external' about this? you either generate the JWT 'internal' or you never generate the JWT and consume a token provided by an external JWT provider.
Typically JWT is used in a 3 party relationship, where Party A is the end-user identity, Party C is the JWT provider that assures Party B (you) that party A authn occurred and are an authentic identity. In a 2 party relationship JWT seems not-fit-for purpose, but can be useful if you make it clear what characteristics of JWT you are using

Comment: Also is the JWT a signature only token (HMAC with pre-shared secret) or is it an encrypted (RSA or ECDSA)? because encrypted means the client generates the private key pair and the JWT is signed using public keys, but the HMAC secret is server-side generated and pre-shared to the client to then reproduce the HMAC and verify the JWT